# PHP цикл выводит неправильную сумму

Tags: php

Я создаю цикл от 0-100 и создаю определенные условия. Например, если число делится на 3 без остатка вывести строку, но у меня также есть условие, которое говорит подсчитать сумму всех чисел, которые делятся на 5 без остатка. И сумма выводится неправильно(735), а должно быть 1050. А так получается потому что есть числа, которые делятся и на 3 и на 5. И при первом условии он забирает себе половину чисел и при втором условии они уже не рассматриваются в сумме, например не входят числа 15,30 и т.д. Как исправить эту логическую ошибку?

Код:

```
    for($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
        echo "<p class='loop'>";
            if($i % 3 == 0) {
                echo "Число $i делится на 3 без остатка";
            } elseif($i % 5 == 0) {
                echo $i;
                $sum += $i;
            } else {
                echo $i;
                if($i == 100) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        echo "</p>";


        echo "<p>";
            echo "Числа деленные на 5 без остатка, сумма: $sum"; // выводит 735, что неправильно
        echo "</p>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    if($i % 3 == 0) {
        echo "<p class='loop'>Число $i делится на 3 без остатка</p>";
    }
    if($i % 5 == 0) {
        $sum += $i;
    }
    //echo $i; Если надо выводить число
}

    echo "<p>";
        echo "Числа деленные на 5 без остатка, сумма: $sum"; // выводит 735, что неправильно
    echo "</p>";
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!